# How to concatenate a multidimensional array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have two multi-dimensional arrays:

```
% Dimensions not matrix multiplication
array1 = a*b*c*d 
array2 = a*b*c*e
```

and I want to concatenate the array as:

```
a*b*c*(d+e).
```

Is this possible in MATLAB without loop?

I've tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
array3 = [array1;array2] % does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use Matlab's [`cat` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), concatenating in the 4th dimension as follows:

```
array3 = cat(4, array1, array2)
```

---

Note from the above linked docs, that what you have tried is concatenation in the 1st dimension, 
"`cat(1, A, B)` is the same as `[A; B]`."

Comment: *"It didn't work"* - Please provide the output it gives you for a small example, compared to the output you expected, and why it doesn't work. *"I already tried that"* - It's impossible for us to know that unless you include all of the things which you have tried in your question... feel free to make an edit to your Q so it can be better answered